# Airflow 2.0 - Scheduler is unable to find serialized DAG in the serialized_dag table

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have 2 files inside dags directory - dag_1.py and dag_2.py

dag_1.py creates a static DAG and dag_2.py creates dynamic DAGs based on external json files at some location.

The static DAG (created by dag_1.py) contains a task at a later stage which generates some of these input json files for dag_2.py and dynamic DAGs are created in this manner.

This used to work fine with Airflow 1.x versions where DAG Serialization was not used. But with Airflow 2.0 DAG Serialization has become mandatory. Sometimes, I get the following exception in the Scheduler when dynamic DAGs are spawned -

```
[2021-01-02 06:17:39,493] {scheduler_job.py:1293} ERROR - Exception when executing SchedulerJob._run_scheduler_loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/global/packages/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1275, in _execute
    self._run_scheduler_loop()
  File "/global/packages/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1377, in _run_scheduler_loop
    num_queued_tis = self._do_scheduling(session)
  File "/global/packages/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1474, in _do_scheduling
    self._create_dag_runs(query.all(), session)
  File "/global/packages/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 1557, in _create_dag_runs
    dag = self.dagbag.get_dag(dag_model.dag_id, session=session)
  File "/global/packages/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 62, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/global/packages/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 171, in get_dag
    self._add_dag_from_db(dag_id=dag_id, session=session)
  File "/global/packages/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 227, in _add_dag_from_db
    raise SerializedDagNotFound(f"DAG '{dag_id}' not found in serialized_dag table")
airflow.exceptions.SerializedDagNotFound: DAG 'dynamic_dag_1' not found in serialized_dag table
```

After this the scheduler gets terminated which is expected.
When I check the table manually after this error, I am able to see the DAG entry in it.

This issue is not reproducible all the time. What can be the probable cause for this? Is there any Airflow configuration which I should try tweaking?

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your DAG

Comment: Does the DAG structure really matter here? On restarting the scheduler, I can run the same dynamically spawned DAG.

I wanted to know if this has something to do with concurrency between DAG parsing and scheduling. As I can see the DAG entry in the serialized_dag table manually, is it possible that this entry was added later by the DagFileProcessor in the table after scheduler failed to find the DAG entry in it?

Comment: As a quick fix, you can run airflow DB init once again, I think it fixes the DB state and the scheduler starts running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13893 which will be released as part for Airflow 2.0.1.

Will release Airflow 2.0.1 next week (8 Feb 2021 - most likely).

Comment: Thank you kaxil. The fix seems to be working fine.

Comment: still hapening for me even in later releases!!

Comment: Happening for me as well on 2.1.4 @AramisNSR did you have any luck finding a solution? Although my issue happens sporadically

Comment: @walker_4 unfortunately our self-assured Mr,Kaxil closed this issue everywhere and never let anyone comment it anywhere so I only remember that I wanted to comment my answer to a github related to this issue but he closed it before I do answer, unfortunately now I forgot..

Comment: You can still post the reply on the PR Aramis. The reason that issue is closed is the PR intended to fix it has worked for most cases. "SERIALIZED DAG not found" error is a very generic error that can happen for many reasons, primarily how the DAG is generated.

Comment: I had even replied to your comment on the PR the exact same thing and asked you to create a Github issue so we can help you and future readers:

Comment: Check: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13893#issuecomment-935740190

Answer (score 8):

We had the same issue after updating in the following order:

1. 1.10.12 -> 1.10.14
2. 1.10.14 -> 2.0.0

I've followed their guide through, and we had no issues until at some random point after a few hours scheduler started crashing complaining about random DAGs not being found in the database.

Our deployment procedure involves clearing out `/opt/airflow/dags` folder and doing a clean install every time (we store dags and supporting code in python packages)

So every now and then on 1.10.x version we had cases when scheduler parsed an empty folder and wiped serialized dags from the database, but it always was able to restore the picture on next parse

Apparently in 2.0, as a part of the effort to make scheduler HA, they fully separated DAG processor and scheduler. Which leads to a race condition:

- if scheduler job hits a database *before* DAG processor has updated *serialized_dag* table values, it finds nothing and crashes
- if luck is on your side, the above will not happen and you won't see this exception

In order to get rid of this problem, I disabled scheduling of all DAGs by updating `is_paused` in the database, restarted the scheduler and once it generated serialized dags, turned all dags back ON

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. I have created a new issue in their official github repo. They have acknowledged it with medium priority and have added it for Airflow 2.0.1 milestone. Hope this bug gets resolved.

Comment: @DivyanshJamuaar do you have a link to that issue?

Comment: @TheNumenorean, Yes - https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13504

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment so having to leave an answer, but:

1. is this a clean 2.0 install or an upgrade of your old 1.10.x instance? and
2. are you recycling the names?

I literally just hit this problem  (I found this question googling to see who else was in the same boat).

In my case, it's an upgraded existing 1.10.x install, and although the dags were generated dynamically, the names were recycled. I was getting errors clicking on the dag in the GUI *and* it was killing the scheduler.

Turns Out(TM), deleting the dags entirely using the 'trashcan' button in the GUI overview and letting them regenerate fixed it (as in, the problem immediately went away and hasn't recurred in the last 30 minutes).

At a guess, it smells to me like maybe some aspect of the dynamic dags wasn't properly migrated in the `db upgrade` step, and wiping them out and letting them fully regenerate fixed the problem. Obviously, you lose all your history etc, but (in my case at least) that's not necessarily a big deal.

Comment: Mine is a clean 2.0 install. But I still happen to see this issue.

Comment: @argibbs did this issue come back for you/did you find a way to resolve? It is only happening in one of our batches which dynamically triggers other dags, and not others

Answer (score 0):

**Selected answer didn't work for me(after bashing my head for few hours).
Heres what works:**

Just go to the backend database(postgresql) and delete all the records regarding `logs, task instances, faild task and ...` **but dont delete the main tables(if you cant tell the diffrence, just remove the tables i mentioned)**

then go and do `airflow db init`

seems like old data about obsolete and deleted dags and tasks can really turn airflow into a mess. delete the mess, get it working.